# Is it possible to deliver digital content to a user's google drive account?

Tags: file, file-transfer, google-drive-api

Without using Google Checkout, I would like to provide a link that allows a user to download digital content directly to their Google Drive account.  Does anyone have advice on how this might achieved?

1. We have our own shopping cart system and host my own content.
2. We simply wish to provide a link to our content that transfers the digital content to the location of the consumer's choosing.

--Charles

Comment: Example of what I am looking to do....

See: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk

I would like to add a button just like the "Add to Dropbox" button, except I want to "Add to Google Drive".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently don't provide such widgets for web developers. You can however use the REST API to accomplish such a thing.

Please refer to the [Drive API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/insert) for how to do it server-side. For a client-side application (full JavaScript), you can refer to the StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330992/authorization-of-google-drive-using-javascript/10331393#10331393).

The Drive SDK currently requires applications to be installed in a user's account through the Chrome Web Store; we are actively working on making the story better for users and developers so stay tuned!

Comment: Thank you.  I'll review your references.