# google drive javascript api gapi.client.drive.files undefined

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

The JavaScript example to list files of Google Drive uses `gapi.client.drive.files.list()`.
When trying to use this method I get the error "Cannot read property 'files' of undefined".

The issue and a workaround are already described under [Google Drive API javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315962)

Is the documentation under https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it incorrect? Or is there a way to use the API as described.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315962/google-drive-api-javascript

Comment: @SteveBazyl: This is not a duplicate; this asks if there is a circumstance for which the example in the documentation is correct (the alternative being that the example is incorrect). The other question asks how to fix the error.

Comment: This will fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589794/call-gapi-client-load-before-all-my-executions-correct

Answer (score 19):

The JavaScript example is correct, but you have to make sure that you only use `gapi.client.drive.files` (and the other Drive-specific resources) when the Drive library is loaded, i.e. after:

```
gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', callback);
```

Answer (score 8):

If it works fine after writing `gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', callback)`, then all good. In my case it does not work so I wrote below code.

```
gapi.load('client', function () {
                gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function () {
                    var file = gapi.client.drive.files.get({ 'fileId': fileId });
                    file.execute(function (resp) {
                        //Write you code with resp variable
                    });

                });
            });
```