# TypeError: gapi.client is undefined error while downloading files from file picker

Tags: javascript, html, download, google-drive-api, filepicker

I have implemented a google file picker in HTML and JS. I have created a client credentials and in the verge of downloading the files from file picker. My code is

```
  <!DOTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My website</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

      // The Browser API key obtained from the Google API Console.
      var developerKey = '############################';

      // The Client ID obtained from the Google API Console. Replace with your own Client ID.
      var clientId = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';

      // Scope to use to access user's photos.
      var scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';

      var appId = "1255s8a2s";

      var pickerApiLoaded = false;
      var oauthToken;

      // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
      function onApiLoad() {
        gapi.load('auth2', onAuthApiLoad);
        gapi.load('picker', onPickerApiLoad);
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2',handleClientLoad);
      }
    function handleClientLoad() {
            gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
            window.setTimeout(onAuthApiLoad,1);
        }


      function onAuthApiLoad() {
        var authBtn = document.getElementById('auth');
        authBtn.disabled = false;
        authBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
          gapi.auth2.authorize({
            client_id: clientId,
            scope: scope
          }, handleAuthResult);
        });
      }

      function onPickerApiLoad() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
        createPicker();
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
          createPicker();
        }
      }

      // Create and render a Picker object for picking user Photos.
      function createPicker() {
        if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
    var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
        view.setMimeTypes("image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg");
          var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
          enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN).
          enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED).
              setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
          setAppId(appId).
          addView(view).
              setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
              setCallback(pickerCallback).
              build();
          picker.setVisible(true);
        }
      }
      // A simple callback implementation.
      function pickerCallback(data) { 
        var url = 'nothing';
    var ids=[];
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
    var ln = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS];
    for(i=0;i<ln.length;i++) {
         ids[i] = data.docs[i].id; 
     gapi.client.drive.files.get({'fileId': ids[1]});
      }
        }
    }



</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Welcome to detect the colours of your image </h1>
<p> Please upload required images. Let us detect what wonderful colours do your images have</p>
<form id="upload-form" action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type = "file" name="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
<form method = "POST" action="/gdrive">
    <button type="button" id="auth">upload from google</button>

</form>

<div id="result"></div>

<!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=init" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=loadPicker"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

After reading [google drive javascript api gapi.client.drive.files undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262884/google-drive-javascript-api-gapi-client-drive-files-undefined), I decided to add `gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', callback);`  in my code. However the result remains the same. I could not initialize the gapi.client, The drive api is enabled. I am new to Javascript, Can anyone please help me download the files using file ids. The File ids are stored in ids[] array in the code.

Thank you for trying to help me out