# What is "gapi.client.people.people.get"?

Tags: google-api

I'm reading this getting started document:

https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/start.md

In Option1, the following code is written:

```
gapi.client.people.people.get({
      'resourceName': 'people/me',
      'requestMask.includeField': 'person.names'
    })
```

Why `.people.people`? I want to know the details of this syntax. If I use google drive API, do I write `gapi.client.drive.drive.get`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this question lets start with the [Discovery services api](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/using)

> The Discovery API provides a list of Google APIs for retrieving a machine-readable "Discovery document" metadata for each API.

The reason we are looking at this is because the [Google apis js client](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) library which you are using gapi was generated using the discovery services api.  [apis-client-generator](https://github.com/google/apis-client-generator)

Then lets look at the discovery dock for [people api](https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1)

If you check under resources you get

- contactGroups
- contactGroups.Members
- otherContacts
- people
- people.conversations

Then each resource has a group of methods under and the people resource has a method called get.

So `people.people.get` is actually `{API}.{resource}.{method}`

This is just how google chose to build up the API.

Now the google drive api also has a group of resources

- About
- Changes
- Channels
- Comments
- Files
- Permissions
- Replies
- Revisons
- Drives

There is a method called gapi.client.drive.drives.get  Which is drive api, drives resource, get method which will return a drives resource.

If your actually after files then its probably more like gapi.client.drive.files.get  Which is drive api, files resource, file get method which would return a file resource.

Answer (score 0):

From the [API Discovery Document](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/discovery.md):

> For each method defined in the API Discovery Document, a corresponding method is constructed on the `gapi.client` object.
>
> For example, The People API's methods are under `gapi.client.people`.
>
> The People API has the methods `people.get` and `people.connections.list`.
>
> [T]he generated methods can be called as follows:
>
> `gapi.client.people.people.get(...)`
>
> `gapi.client.people.people.connections.list(...)`
>
> You can view API Methods on [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/).

So `.people.people` means:

> Using the `People API`-equivalent method `people`, call the `people.get(...)` method.

To use the [Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference), you would query against `gapi.client.drive` with your method name. For example, `gapi.client.drive.channels.stop(...)`.

An important note from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14265544/14956277): you must load the Drive API before using it.

```
gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', callback);
```