# Google Drive using JavaScript: Handling file content

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Two months ago, in [Authorization of Google Drive using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10331393/1530236),
[@Nivco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1313169/nivco) was writing about "**Handling file content**", a very tantalizing:

> We could also improve the file content server so that it supports XHR
>   requests.

So, where could "we" find news or roadmaps, information *et coetera* about this feature?

---

<sup>Actually, this question is a reply... (to [another question](https://plus.google.com/110487324451850883514/posts/8W7HuS76whE))</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Here is a short example using [CORS](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/CORS).
The ID of the file is stored in variable <`theID`> ; this ID is unique and won't change as long as the file is not deleted (a [trashed](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#labels.trashed) file is not deleted).

- First `gapi.client.request` retrieves the downloadUrl property ; the returned value is a short lived value ;
- Then, the `callback: function` sends an authenticated request in order to retrieve the contents of the file, thanks to its <downloadUrl> ;
- And the winner is… returned via `onreadystatechange = function( theProgressEvent )`.

.

```
gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/drive/v2/files/'+theID,
    'method': 'GET',
    callback: function ( theResponseJS, theResponseTXT ) {
        var myToken = gapi.auth.getToken();
        var myXHR   = new XMLHttpRequest();
        myXHR.open('GET', theResponseJS.downloadUrl, true );
        myXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + myToken.access_token );
        myXHR.onreadystatechange = function( theProgressEvent ) {
            if (myXHR.readyState == 4) {
//          1=connection ok, 2=Request received, 3=running, 4=terminated
                if ( myXHR.status == 200 ) {
//              200=OK
                    console.log( myXHR.response );
                }
            }
        }
        myXHR.send();
    }
});
```

<sup>tested with "Chrome 20.0.1132.57 m" and "Firefox 14.0.1"</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The file download endpoint now supports CORS requests. I have updated the body of the answer to [Authorization of Google Drive using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330992/authorization-of-google-drive-using-javascript/10331393#10331393) yesterday actually to make sure it reflects the latest state of the API. I just removed that trailing comment you are referring to :)

Comment: Very efficient, as usual. However, may I ask for a small example using CORS in order to download a file, similar to the ones given as example for uploading? By the way, how might we set parameters to create+upload a file and link it to some folder(s), in only one request?