# How do I use exportlinks from javascript to download a Gdoc using Drive SDK?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to download content from a Google docs file using Javascript using the Drive SDK.

I retrieve the metadata, and parse the exportLinks to get a URL
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=xxx&exportFormat=html

My code is similar to [Google Drive using JavaScript: Handling file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578506/google-drive-using-javascript-handling-file-content) except I'm using exportLinks:text/html instead of downloadUrl.

If I try to retrieve that URL, I get "405 OPTIONS method not allowed".

(as an aside, if I download a non-docs file using the downloadUrl, all is OK).

So I'm guessing that either:-
a) I shouldn't be using Drive to retrieve Docs files
b) I should be using the exportLinks is some other fashion, or 
c) I need to implement the same iframe workaround that is used for upload here [Does https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files really support CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617229/solved-does-https-www-googleapis-com-upload-drive-v2-files-really-support-co)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export links do not currently support CORS. It is something we are working on, so sorry about that.

If you can use the iframe hack for now, until we get it working, then please do.