# Update file content on google drive using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Based on @Nvico great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10331393/37980) i was able to upload files to google drive, the problem is the code on the answer creates a new file each time, is there a way given an already created file id to update its content directly (using [Files:update](http://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) api) without creation of a new one ?

currently my solution is to use [Files:delete](http://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete) api each time i want to update the file to remove the old one then create a new file using @Nvico code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the drive.files.insert endpoint, you can use almost the same code to send an update request to the drive.files.update endpoint:

```
/**
 * Update existing file.
 *
 * @param {String} fileId ID of the file to update.
 * @param {Object} fileMetadata existing Drive file's metadata.
 * @param {File} fileData File object to read data from.
 * @param {Function} callback Callback function to call when the request is complete.
 */
function updateFile(fileId, fileMetadata, fileData, callback) {
  const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
  const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octect-stream';
    // Updating the metadata is optional and you can instead use the value from drive.files.get.
    var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
    var multipartRequestBody =
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
        JSON.stringify(fileMetadata) +
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
        '\r\n' +
        base64Data +
        close_delim;

    var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files/' + fileId,
        'method': 'PUT',
        'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart', 'alt': 'json'},
        'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
        },
        'body': multipartRequestBody});
    if (!callback) {
      callback = function(file) {
        console.log(file)
      };
    }
    request.execute(callback);
  }
}
```

The main difference is in the request URL and method:

```
PUT /upload/drive/v2/files/<FILE_ID>
```

Comment: thanks it works , i have tried changing the end point only in the  original code my self but it didn't work , may be because of the alt:json ? i don't know may be it was a typo in the url.. thanks any way :)

Comment: You might have forgotten to change the method from `POST` to `PUT`. The `alt=json` query parameter is useful when sending text content data to let the API know that the JSON document is the metadata and the other part is the content.

Comment: @Alain - Can you please help what to pass in fileData ? Trying to pass string doesn't work. Which object it needs and how to get it?