# External Javascript client Authorization for Google Drive upload

Tags: javascript, upload, client, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I'm developing client application based on Javascript that won't be a Google App. I can create files on Drive but have a problem with a authorization when trying to upload the content.

A comment in:
[Authorization of Google Drive using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330992/authorization-of-google-drive-using-javascript)
seems to say that the client must be a google App to write to Drive but until I saw this comment I thought this was possible reinforced by my ability to create empty files. Please will somebody clarify this?

I'm using code similar to response 3 of the post however I only get the login screen nothing asks for Google Drive permissions.

My code uses the 2 part "media" upload method described in [How do I add/create/insert files to Google Drive through the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317638/inserting-file-to-google-drive-through-api/10323612#10323612)

As I say the file create works but the upload fails:

PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v1/files/0Bxbwly1hLFXnVmQ3Snh3ZXVOYVE?uploadType=media&alt=json&key= 401 (Unauthorized) rs=AItRSTNkdxHWOPN1C6XNGC9ea3U4KWDICw:128
 :response>{"error" {"message" "Invalid Credentials", "errors" [{"domain" "global", "reason" "authError", "message" "Invalid Credentials", "locationType" "header", "location" "Authorization"}], "code" 401}}

I'm not using Javascript direct rather Clojurescript so it is possible there is a problem with my upload call. The lack of anything asking for Google drive permissions would seem to indicate a real authorization problem but then I would have expected not to get an access_token when requesting "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive". Thanks

Update....
I've finally solved this: If I request "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file" rather than the greater privileges "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" then the authentication requests access to Drive and the file content is uploaded.

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer.

Comment: I tried to, stackoverflow wouldn't accept the answer, it reported that I had to wait 6 hours to do this; why I don't know.

Comment: Next time you visit just make sure to accept it :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've finally solved this: If I request "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file" rather than the greater privileges https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive then the authentication requests access to Drive and the file content is uploaded.