# google javascript api client and multiple accounts

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to use the google apis with multiple users.  Does anyone know how to do this.  I want to allow users to add different accounts and get information for each of their different accounts.  The google js library seems to always use the same logged in user.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/13366254 and http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=11