# Is there a way to support multiple Google Accounts when authorizing using the JS client API library on Safari on iOS 6?

Tags: safari, ios6, google-drive-api, google-api-client

On our site http://www.draw.io/ in the top right there's a Google Drive integration button that uses the [JS API client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/GettingStarted) to authorize. This works fine everywhere, except for Safari on iOS 6. When clicking on it a new tab flicks up briefly then disappears. From our logging [our authorize call](https://github.com/jgraph/draw.io/blob/master/war/js/diagramly/GoogleDrive.js#L81) is invoked, but [our callback function](https://github.com/jgraph/draw.io/blob/master/war/js/diagramly/GoogleDrive.js#L110) is never reached.

We followed the tips in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366254/is-it-possible-to-be-able-to-correctly-select-any-available-google-account-to-us) to get a reasonable level of multiple account handling working and it works correctly in all other environments we've tested, including iOS 5. If we set the immediate parameter to true in the [gapi.auth.authorize call](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/ReferenceDocs) the login works on iOS 6 because the popup is avoided. However, this only works for users with a single Google Account, if they have multiple accounts their default account is always used.

If, when, you read this question the main site doesn't show this behaviour, it's probably that we've patched it to detect Safari on iOS 6 and set the immediate flag to true. This fixes part of the problem so users on iOS 6 can use Drive with our app *at all*, but we still need to support multiple accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested again today and this works correctly on iOS 5, 6 and 7.