# Server-side flow for Google Drive API authorization of a javascript Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I was reading @Nivco answer to [Authorization of Google Drive using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330992/authorization-of-google-drive-using-javascript) and saw:

"...all you have to do it is use server-side code to process the authorization code returned after the Drive server-side flow (you need to exchange it for an access token and a refresh token). That way, only on the first flow will the user be prompted for authorization. After the first time you exchange the authorization code, the auth page will be bypassed automatically.

Server side samples to do this is available in our documentation."

Having read the documentation I am still pretty confused about how to process the authorization code and ultimately pass the access and refresh tokens to my Chrome extension so that it can proceed without the server for future requests. Can someone provide an example of the server-side code to do this?

As background I have a Chrome Extension with several thousand users that is built on the Google DocList API but I am trying to transition to the Drive API since the other one is being deprecated. Ideally my code would be entirely stand alone as an extension but I'm willing to accept the single authorization request through my server that Nivco's answer requires.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We've just ported our JavaScript application from using server to client flow. We've removed the server part entirely, it's not needed any longer.

You can see the [source code that we used online](http://www.draw.io/js/diagramly/DriveClient.js), it's available uncompressed.

Comment: Link provided is 404 :(