# Save a file from Chrome extension to Google Drive

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I have created a chrome extension to learn English that build a dictionary with source/translation, etc.

Now, I want to send this "file" (I will/would build a "file" with the dictionary entries) to Google Drive and use this file in my Android app.

But I want to save this file not on my personal Drive account, but in the Drive of the current user, the user who uses the chrome extension (if this user has a Drive account, of course).

In all the examples I found, they define the OAuth for "my" account ("my" = the chrome developer in the `manifest.json`, so, static).

Is there a way to save in the drive of the user?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the OAuth - it does indeed save in the user's drive - you however need to configure your extension as an app in your Google account - https://console.developers.google.com/project

Comment: hello, drive rest api (v3) allow to get and save file/folder etc. (with javascript)

Comment: Have you checked this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330992/authorization-of-google-drive-using-javascript/10331393#10331393

Answer (score 0):

Use the '*chrome.storage*' API to store, retrive and track changes to user data.

Please refer to the link: 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: hello, no the answer is good, we can use the storage sync for save on google account but the problem is the limit quotabytes and the max items : 512, with a simple dictionnary we explose this limit. So, Xan is right, we can not use this solution.