# Google Drive API for C or C++

Tags: c++, c, google-drive-api

Is there a C or C++ API for Google Drive?

I've looked at the Google API developer website, but there I can only find APIs for Java, PHP, Ruby, Python, and C#.

I would like to develop a simple C/C++ command-line binary to sync a local folder to a remote folder.

Comment: PS: I have described a way to upload files to drive in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317638/inserting-file-to-google-drive-through-api/10323612#10323612 That may help you.

Answer (score 6):

Currently, there are no official C or C++ libraries. This is a contribution that would be very gratefully received, so please let us know if you take it on.

There are some usages, [for example](https://github.com/jcline/fuse-google-drive) which might help you on your way.

Comment: thank you. just to let people interested know that finally i've look at, which contains usefull code: http://match065.github.com/grive/