# Can't open uploaded file in Google Drive using API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-drive-api, xmlhttprequest, multipart

I am sending a request in Google Drive API version 3. 
I have a Base64 image. 
I have this code,

```
var callback = function(ret, raw) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(raw);
    self.uploadUrl = obj.gapiRequest["data"]["headers"]["location"];
    const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
      const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
      const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsBinaryString(data);
      reader.onload = function(e) {
      console.log(reader.result);
        var contentType = data.type || 'application/octet-stream';
        var metadata = {
          'name': data.name,
          'mimeType': contentType
        };

        var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
        var multipartRequestBody = reader.result;
        console.log(self.uploadUrl);
        var request = gapi.client.request({
            'path': self.uploadUrl.replace('https://www.googleapis.com', ''),
            'method': 'PUT',
            'headers': {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.state.token, 'Content-Length': data.size, 'Content-Type': data.type
            },
            'body': multipartRequestBody});
          var callback2 = function(file) {
            console.log(file)
          };
        request.execute(callback2);
      }

    };
```

With that request, I console.log this message: `Object {kind: "drive#file", id: "0B0jyCEQS7DFib19iX2FLYm1yR28", name: "MyFileTitle", mimeType: "image/jpeg"}`

So I assuming here that I successfully uploaded a file. But when I check the file in Google Drive, I can't open it. No preview of the file also. I downloaded the file, still can't open it. What is wrong in here? anyone can help me?

This is the response header,

```
Request URL:https://content.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UoIhN3QtsUc1qLW5N_3yG-NOyl9Nm-maYY7T5X4dQbMK_hxu9M-E9L1247jeLEtRQJd8w8IA_GH_6HSWbNrFnocfmt31-oA0iXXHTcZE7k2aIIAvHQ
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:216.58.197.170:443
```

this is my request header,

```
Authorization:Bearer <MY_TOKEN>
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Origin:https://content.googleapis.com
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

uploadType:resumable
upload_id:AEnB2UoIhN3QtsUc1qLW5N_3yG-NOyl9Nm-maYY7T5X4dQbMK_hxu9M-E9L1247jeLEtRQJd8w8IA_GH_6HSWbNrFnocfmt31-oA0iXXHTcZE7k2aIIAvHQ
```

The request payload is something like this,

```
ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿÛC       ...
```

Still can't open the file.

This is the creation of the file,

```
submitForm(e){
e.preventDefault();
var data = this.refs.file.files[0];
var self = this;
var metadata = {
    'Content-Length': data.size,
    'name': data.name
};

var contentType = data.type;
var multipartRequestBody = JSON.stringify(metadata);
var request = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/upload/drive/v3/files',
        'method': 'POST',
    'params': {'uploadType': 'resumable'},
    'headers': {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.state.token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'X-Upload-Content-Type': data.type, 'X-Upload-Content-Length': data.size
        },
    'body': multipartRequestBody});

var callback = ...

request.execute(callback);
}
```

The code above is the creation of the file. I added it because maybe the problem is in this part.

Comment: to clarify, the file is there in Google Drive, but you can't open its contents? When you download it, what is its size and how does that size compare with the original image? Have you tried looking at the download using an editor or hex editor to see what's in it?

Comment: The file have the text of the multipart request body.

Comment: In your old code before you changed it, can you try changing "BASE64" to "base64" as demoed in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923927/upload-a-file-to-google-drive-api-using-html5)?

Comment: I get it right? You first create a file with its metadata, then update it in a second call with its content? Why not use directly Google REST API, like this one: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads

Comment: I am confused with the line `var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);`. `base64Data` is not used at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Object {kind: "drive#file", id: "0B0jyCEQS7DFib19iX2FLYm1yR28", name: "MyFileTitle", mimeType: "image/jpeg"}

You are uploading a file of type `image/jpeg`  but the name is `MyFileTitle`.  I think you are confusing drive it cant open a file if it doesn't know what it is.

Try changing it to `MyFileTitle.jpg`.