# Can client save their documents in google drive through my project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to add my clients google drive in my project. it's a part of my project for secure their data in google drive. so my question is how can i do this work in my project like very first time i get the access and then i have the full control of their google drive.

Comment: [C# Desktop application. Simple example how to upload a file to Google Drive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11994650/3060520)

Comment: You can do it, you will have to integrate their API in to your project

Comment: i can add my drive with the help of google product wizard but i want to add my clients google drive with my project.

Comment: have a look on google C# client libraries there are binaries and samples