# RE: Inserting File to Google Drive through API

Tags: google-drive-api

The following StackOverflow question seems to be widely referenced on this subject.

[How do I add/create/insert files to Google Drive through the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317638/inserting-file-to-google-drive-through-api)

These simple directions failed for me.  Here's what I send Google:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHES6ZRO8SLGjreb1DbNju62WF-AHES6ZRO8SLGjreb1DbNju62
Content-Length: 347
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="1366986113131560"

--1366986113131560
Content-Type: application/json

{"mimeType":"text/plain","title":"hi.txt","parents":[{"id":"0BxnfVWt9egI_VDJnbFBpZDExTmM"}]}
--1366986113131560
Content-Type: text/plain

setPendingSave
loadSegments
setSequence
addSegment
setspanformat
setspanformat
hidespanformat
setspanformat
setspanformat
hidespanformat
--1366986113131560--
```

When I submit this, Google responds with the error message:

*Multipart content has too many non-media parts*

I don't want belabor this point, but it would be nice to demonstrate that the API works without having to rely on Google libraries.

Comment: By accident, I tested again using the Mime-Type "image/jpeg" and the upload succeeded.  Is "text/plain" not a valid file type?

Comment: Additionally, setting a "Content-Transfer-Encoding" value in a sub-part header results in the message "malformed multipart body".

Answer (score 0):

Please use https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart as your endpoint. If you don't include `uploadType=multipart`, we can extract metadata and content separately.

Comment: Your statement is incorrect.  See my first comment above:  A file was successfully inserted by using a different, and incorrect, mime-type.

Comment: Metadata could be represented as `text/plain` at the infrastructure we (Google Drive) depend on uploads. It assumes that you're trying to upload metadata in two different formats which is illegal. That's why I'm suggesting you to separate the requests.

Comment: I've just realized you're not using multipart upload type. Fixing my answer.