# how to insert an attachment in a timeline using google-api-nodejs-client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, attachment, google-mirror-api

I am trying the Google Glass Mirror APIs now. My test app is a simple node.js/express server with googleapis (https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client).

So far I could do almost all the basic operations of timelines successfully, such as list/get/update/delete, without attachments. Here is how I insert a timeline card:

```
var googleapis = require('googleapis');
app.all('/timeline_insert', function(req, res) {
  var timeline = {'text': req.query.text};
  googleapis.discover('mirror', 'v1')
        .execute(function(err, client) {
      client.mirror.timeline.insert({resource: timeline})
                        .withAuthClient(oauth2client)
                .execute(function(err, result) {
          // ...
      });
  });

}
```

Now I want to go one more step further to test the attachment features. However, I have no idea how to use the APIs via googleapis and node.js. Is there any sample code for the attachment operations, such as insert/get? I know I can always use raw HTTP format to do it. But since googleapis already provides the APIs, I just want to directly use them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Node.js client library, which is based on the JavaScript client library, has no built-in support for media upload: you will need to build the request "manually".

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10323612/1106381) should help you get started on building this request.

More information on Google's media upload protocol can be found in our [documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/media-upload).