# Angular 2+ HTTP POST and GDrive API. Resumable file upload with name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload files to Google Drive in Angular 2. So far I am able to upload files, but without `title` and they are "Untitled"

Here is code to do that:

```
gDriveUploader(file): Promise<any> {
let authToken = tokenHere;
const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/`
    let formData:FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', file, file.name);
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken
    });
    headers.append('Accept', file.type);
    let options = new RequestOptions ({ 
      headers: headers,
    });

    console.log('OPTIONS: ', options)

    return this.http.post(`${url}`, formData, options)
        .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json())
           .catch(e=>console.log(e));
}
```

I know, that in order to send metadata with file, I have to add this metadata to `Request` body and use at `multipart` or `resumable` upload types. But here I faced issue after issue and just can't make it properly.

I completely messed up. Here is on of my approaches with `resumable` upload type:

```
gDriveUploader(file): Promise<any> {
let authToken = token;
const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable`
    console.log('FILE TO UPLOAD: ', file)
    let formData:FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', file, file.name);
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', //if remove "Bad Content" Error
      //'Content-Length': file.size, not sure if this one right?
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions ({ 
      headers: headers,
    });

    return this.http.post(`${url}`, formData, options)
        .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json())
           .catch(e=>console.log(e));
}
```

that's not only two of my approaches...

According to Drive API for `resumable` upload:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable 

HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Type: image/jpeg
X-Upload-Content-Length: 2000000
```

What is `Content-Length: 38`? it's file length and I can just use `file.size`?

With `multipart` I can't figure out how to add those boundary separator in the request.

I saw some Q and A, that `multipart` were not supported by Angular, but that was 1-2 year ago. What about now?

Can I somehow use resumable upload to GDrive with additional file metadata using standard Angular features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So. A bit more research on how API works. I came up with the following solution for resumable file upload. Main Idea, that first time I have to make a request and "set metadata" for my file and get response with the link, where to upload the file. And this link came as one of the `response header` called `location`.

Here is fully working code. Just pass `File` object to the first function.

I just quickly made 2 functions for this. First one will set metadata (just name) and call second function to upload just binary data.

```
gDriveUploader(file): Promise<any> {
  let authToken = token
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable`
      let headers = new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      });
      let options = new RequestOptions ({ 
        headers: headers,
      });
      return this.http.post(`${url}`, {name: file.fullName}, options) //just set the name
          .toPromise()
            .then(response => this.gDriveUploadFile(file, response.headers.get('location'))) //call second function to upload `file` to proper URI from response
            .then(response => {
                let id = response.json().id //parse id of uploaded file
                let resp = {fileName: file.fullName, fileType: file.fileType, fileSize: file.size, fileId: id} //create an object with file file properties, if you need that
                return resp // return object back to function that called this service
            })
            .catch(e=>console.log(e));
  }
```

Second function to upload data:

```
gDriveUploadFile(file, url): Promise<any> { //file and url we got from first func
  let authToken = token
      let headers = new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'X-Upload-Content-Type': file.type
      });
      let options = new RequestOptions ({ 
        headers: headers,
      });
      return this.http.post(`${url}`, file, options) //call proper resumable upload endpoint and pass just file as body
          .toPromise()
  }
```

Maybe solution not ideal, so far I do not handle errors here and do not use `resumable` features like uploading by chunks, just upload file at once. But hopefully if someone else stuck with GDrive uploading can get an idea.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.