# How to create file into Google Drive with post request in angular?

Tags: angular, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a file in angular but I can't set the parameter like for the example `name`

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DriveService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  token: string = localStorage.getItem('tokenGoogle');

  headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.token}`)
    .set('Accept', `application/json`)
    .set('Content-Type', `application/json`);

  creaFileDrive(nome: string): Observable<DriveResultFile> {

    return this.http.post<DriveResultFile>('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?key=AIzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&uploadType=multipart',
      {name: 'pata'}, // HERE THE NAME DON'T SET
      {headers: this.headers}).pipe(
      map(x => {
        return x;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

clearly, this is not my goal

[image: this is the result]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use multipart upload
   https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/multipart-upload with
   different headers for file metadata and actual file. Me myself stuck
   there, didn't found how to add boundaries to separate request
   headers in Angular 2+
2. Upload file in two requests. First to create empty file with
   metadata (response will provide id of the file) and second to
   actually "update" the file.
3. Use resumable upload. First request to "setup metadata" (will not
   even create empty file) and get "special link" where to send request
   to upload actual file. And this approach have some other features,
   like uploading in
   chunks.https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload

Here is the link to another Question with implementation of resumable upload in Angular 2 and DRIVE REST API V3

[Angular 2+ HTTP POST and GDrive API. Resumable file upload with name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305492/angular-2-http-post-and-gdrive-api-resumable-file-upload-with-name)

Comment: the first link is broken. Did you mean https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#multipart